# deleted main Sharepoint site - can't create new one Options

Tags: site-deletion, site-creation

During my experiments with SharePoint 2010 I have deleted the default team site, so when I go to `http://computer_name` I have "404 not found" error.

Now it is impossible to create/add any subsite sites because I would need to browse the parent site which does no longer exist. I cannot also use SharePoint designer - it would simply report the error:

> This site must be created on a server that is running Microsoft SharePoint Foundation. Please choose another location.

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

Go to SharePoint Central Administration and create a new Site Collection for the SharePoint Application associated with your URL. This will create a new default root site.